# The echo command on windows CMD ask me if I want more

Tags: cmd.exe, ms-dos

I was trying to echo something in the Windows command prompt (cmd.exe), I entered the following input :

`echo ^.^`

And noticed that every time I'm passing a string which finish with a "^", it will output :

```
"More ?"
```

What does that mean ?

Comment: I think you've read too much charles dickens  oliver twist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAvCMQ_ok1c    In your case you might need another carrot, or caret rather.   'cos `echo ^` will ask for more, whereas `echo ^^` will be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/echo.mspx?mfr=true) a doc on the command prompt `echo` command (it's an XP document, but the `echo` command hasn't changed much since DOS). Long story short, the caret charactor `^` is an escape character used with the `echo` command if you want to print a pipe or redirection symbol (`|` or `<>` respectively).

Example:

`echo ^^^|^>^<^|^^`

will output:

`^|><|^`

(using 2 `^` in a row (like so `^^`) will print a literal `^`).

If you use it at the end of a line in a batch file, it can be used as 'line continuation', example:

file `echotest.bat` contains:

```
echo Hello from ^
the next line
```

when run will output:

```
Hello from the next line
```

The `More?` is `echo` asking if there's more input (like a pipe or redirection symbol, or just more text).

Hope that helps.

Comment: caret also serves as continuation character (if entered as last char on line) allowing splitting command over multiple lines, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-vista-dos-batch-bat-file; you may want to add it to your answer

Comment: Thanks for the catch @wmz, I've updated my answer with the info.