# Insert line break/special character in string in command line

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I would like to do something like this:

```
set a=dupa;jasiu;karuzela;
set a=%a:;=\n%
echo %a%
```

to get this:

```
dupa
jasiu
karuzela
```

instead of this:

```
dupa\njasiu\nkaruzela\n
```

How do I embed line breaks or special characters in string?

## Warining

The `set b=%a:;=^&echo.%` solution does not put line breaks in your string but actual `&echo.` commands.

Comment: `set a=%a:;= &echo.%` will do the new-line, but it does it in reverse. You could loop over the variable in a `for` loop and echo as well.

Comment: this acutally echos last two lines `jasiu karuzela` and when I call echo `%a%` after that it prints only `dupa`

Comment: Oh. There should be the `echo` instead of of `set` if you just want to display it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [txtechhelp's advice](https://superuser.com/questions/1183502/insert-line-break-special-character-in-string-in-command-line#comment1714280_1183502) is close:

```
==> set a=dupa;jasiu;karuzela;

==> echo %a:;=&echo.%
dupa
jasiu
karuzela


==>
```

However, you need to [escape the `&` ampersand character](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in a `set` command using either the general escape character (`^` caret):

```
==> set b=%a:;=^&echo.%

==> echo %b%
dupa
jasiu
karuzela
```

or using double quotes:

```
==> set "c=%a:;=&echo.%"

==> echo %c%
dupa
jasiu
karuzela
```

You could loop over the `%a%` variable in a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html). 
It's simple **if `%a%` *does not contain other delimiter(s)*** like *space*, *tab*, *comma* or *equals sign*:

```
==> for %f in (%a%) do @echo %f
dupa
jasiu
karuzela

==>
```

Otherwise, **if `%a%` *contains* some other delimiter(s)** like *space*, *tab*, *comma* or *equals sign*:

```
==> set a=dupa;jasiu;karu zela;

==> for %f in (%a%) do @echo %f
dupa
jasiu
karu
zela

==> for %f in ("%a:;=";"%") do @if not "%~f"=="" echo.%~f
dupa
jasiu
karu zela

==>
```

Please note the `%f` loop parameter (above examples copied & pasted from an open `cmd` command window).

**In a batch file**, denominate it properly using ***doubled percent sign*** as `%%f`:

```
for %%f in (%a%) do echo %%f
```

Comment: just make sure not to [`echo ^`](http://superuser.com/questions/744004/batch-file-eats-cpu-and-ram-using-only-echo) :)