# Write multi-line variable to .txt (CMD, NO .bat)

Tags: cmd.exe, environment-variables

I'm successfully **splitting** `%PATH%` into multiple lines like this

```
set t=%PATH:;=^&echo.%
```

then this **displays** each path in new line nicely, just as I want:

```
echo %t%
```

However when I want to **write** variable into a file

```
echo %t% >paths.txt
```

only last line is written to the file.

What am I doing wrong?

## Update

Turns out the `set t=%PATH:;=^&echo.%` command does not replace `;` characters with line breaks (as I was told) but instead replaces it with the `&echo.‌​` command, which is later executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### What am I doing wrong?

You need to surround the last `echo` with `(` and `)`

```
(echo %t%) > paths.txt
```

Corrected batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set t=%PATH:;=^&echo.%
echo %t%
(echo %t%) > paths.txt
:endendlocal
```

Example usage:

```
> test
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\apps\WSCC\Sysinternals Suite
C:\apps\WSCC\NirSoft Utilities
C:\apps\Calibre\
C:\apps\Git\cmd
C:\apps\Git\mingw64\bin
C:\apps\Git\usr\bin
C:\apps\nodejs\
C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Roaming\npm
> type paths.txt
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\apps\WSCC\Sysinternals Suite
C:\apps\WSCC\NirSoft Utilities
C:\apps\Calibre\
C:\apps\Git\cmd
C:\apps\Git\mingw64\bin
C:\apps\Git\usr\bin
C:\apps\nodejs\
C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

---

#### A simpler solution

This solution does not require any brackets in the path to be escaped.

test.cmd:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for %%i in ("%path:;=";"%") do (
  echo %%~i >> paths.txt
)
:endendlocal
```

And from the command line:

```
for %i in ("%path:;=";"%") do echo %~i >> paths.txt
```

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [syntax-brackets](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-brackets.html) - Using parenthesis/brackets to group expressions

Comment: I've already tied this. I got `At this moment \Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin\ was unexpected` (thought it's said in Polish and I'm not sure how original message looks like). I have `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin\` on 3 line in the variable if that helps.

Comment: Let me know If i understand it right. Dose my variable `%t%` stores actual `echo.` commends in itself? that are then tied to be executed? Because I thought my `%t%` variable simply stores a single string that is written to the file...

Comment: It stores `echo` commands in the string. The string looks like `C:\Windows\system32&echo.C:\Windows&echo.C:\Windows\System32\Wbem&echo.C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\&echo.C:\apps\WSCC\Sysinternals Suite&echo.C:\apps\WSCC\NirSoft Utilities&echo.C:\apps\Calibre\&echo.C:\apps\Git\cmd&echo.C:\apps\Git\mingw64\bin&echo.C:\apps\Git\usr\bin&echo.C:\apps\nodejs\&echo.C:\Users\DavidPostill\AppData\Roaming\npm` in my case.

Comment: You need to escape the brackets in `(x86)`

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I've added a much simpler solution to the answer, which does not require any brackets in the path to be escaped

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for solution that works without `.bat` file. Is it possible? Apparently I was cheated with [previous](https://superuser.com/questions/1183502/insert-line-break-special-character-in-string-in-command-line) answer. Is it possible to put `CRLF` bytes in variable?

Comment: @PawełAudionysos I've added a command line solution.

Comment: Can't tell that I fully understand it but it's working finally :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yours `t` should not store special control characters as a part of path like `"`, `&`, `|`, `%` and so on.
If so, then you can just replace the ending `)` character having interference with the parser:

`(echo %t:)=^)%) > a`